# Dependency convergence from the same dependency

Tags: spring, maven, pom.xml, dependency-management, zipkin

i have s basic spring boot/cloud application based on

```
<spring-boot.version>1.5.17.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
<spring-cloud.version>Camden.SR7</spring-cloud.version>
```

But i need spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin with at least 1.3.x.
By importing 1.3.5.RELEASE i get a strange error.
It seems like the same dependency creates a convergence.

Is that easily solavble?

```
[WARNING]
Dependency convergence error for io.zipkin.zipkin2:zipkin:2.7.1 paths to dependency are:
+-my-fancy-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin:1.3.5.RELEASE
    +-io.zipkin.zipkin2:zipkin:2.7.1
and
+-my-fancy-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin:1.3.5.RELEASE
    +-io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:2.5.0
      +-io.zipkin.zipkin2:zipkin:2.6.1
and
+-my-fancy-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin:1.3.5.RELEASE
    +-io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-sender-kafka11:2.5.0
      +-io.zipkin.zipkin2:zipkin:2.6.1
and
+-my-fancy-service:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin:1.3.5.RELEASE
    +-io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-sender-amqp-client:2.5.0
      +-io.zipkin.zipkin2:zipkin:2.6.1
```

Comment: Solved it by upgrading from Camden to Edgware which contains 1.3.5 (and resolving everything around that switch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me or anybody finding this thread:
Solved it by upgrading from Camden to Edgware which contains 1.3.5 (and resolving everything around that switch).

Answer (score 0):

Add a dependencyManagement entry for io.zipkin.zipkin2:zipkin:2.7.1